# android:how to lock the device using voice

Tags: android, locking, screen

I am new to android. I am trying to lock the device using voice . I recorded the voice with media recorder but now How I lock the phone with this voice ? plz any idea.

Comment: What you need is a voice recognizer. The recording per se is useless because you will never say it exactly the same.

Comment: voice commands are executed from server.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, but u need to probably do more work that mere speculation here. A quick brainstorm:

- your app must be a device admin to be able to lock the device
- to lock the device, this device admin could be "told" via a broadcast event routed to it
- the "lock device" event can be raised by another / same app if it can capture from the mic,
  probably forward this to a server that can do speech-to-text (Google has something), then yo app tries to recognize whether the response text matches the "lock" criteria. If it does, then broadcast the "lock" event.

This heavily depends on how good the speech-to-text part is done, otherwise, explore along those lines.

Comment: I just wanted to lock the screen if(boolean==true) how it possible? thanks in advance.